# difficult with duplicate data into cart with user not log in, then log in

Tags: php, mysql, loops

**DB**

cart_tb table

```
row1: product_id = **3**, user_id = 10, ip_addr = '127.0.0.1', etc 
row2: product_id = 4, user_id = 10, ip_addr = '127.0.0.1', etc)
```

if I **first** put an **existing** item in the cart and **then** another product(user do not have yet)

```
row3: product_id = **3**, user_id = 10, ip_addr = '127.0.0.1', etc - will be deleted
row4: product_id = 7, user_id = 10, ip_addr = '127.0.0.1', etc) - will be updated
```

Result: the sql will detect the row and evaluate that there is already an existing item similar to what we're putting in the cart, thus will delete this one.(row3 gets delete)

cart_tb = row1, row2, row3

BUT if I first put a not yet existing product in the cart and then an existing product

result:

```
row3: product_id = 7, user_id = 10, ip_addr = '127.0.0.1', etc) - will be updated
row4: product_id = **3**, user_id = 10, ip_addr = '127.0.0.1', etc - wont delete??? why
```

cart_tb: row1(same product), row2, row3, row4(same product)

```
$sql = "SELECT product_id FROM cart WHERE user_id = -1 AND ip_address = '$ip_add' ";
$stmt = $heidisql->query($sql);

while ($test = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $product_list = $test['product_id'];

  $verify_cart_count = "SELECT COUNT(cart_id) FROM cart WHERE user_id= '$userid' AND product_id = $product_list";

  $verify_cart_row = $heidisql->query($verify_cart_count);
  $data_exists = $verify_cart_row->fetchColumn();
  // echo $data_exists; exit();
  if ($data_exists < 1) {
    //if result = 0, userid will be updated
    $update_cart = "UPDATE cart SET user_id='$userid' WHERE ip_address = '$ip_add' AND user_id = -1";
    $update_cart_result = $heidisql->prepare($update_cart);
    $update_cart_result->execute();

  } else {
    //if result > 0, duplicate row need to be delete
    $remove_exist_product = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE user_id = -1 AND ip_address= '$ip_add' AND product_id = $product_list ";
    $remove_cart_result = $heidisql->prepare($remove_exist_product)->execute();

  }
}
```

I think the while loop may be the problem... I dont want duplicate item for same user in the cart

Comment: ip address is not user unique, you cant use it like this

Comment: I do have userid which is unique/same with productID, also it not the ip that the issue

Comment: Are you building your own cart or are you using an existing cart?

Comment: yes already build cart, can add/modify/del product fine, I want that when user not log in he/she can still add product in cart, then when log in, the cart data will transfer data(row3/row4) to the already pre-existing cart data (row1,row2) but without the duplicate

Comment: not that i understand your logic or attitude, but, shouldn't delete use $userid?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: check if exists first, if yes update, if not, insert

Comment: i already check if data exist, if result > 0 mean that there are duplicate data, delete that data, else update

Comment: Please add your table definition. Also, what is "a not yet existing product"?

Comment: I'm certain this is a typo... but given your issues, what is `'product_item_id'` that isn't present in your SQL statement that is used to build your array, but you call it as a key to that array inside your WHILE loop.

Comment: Can you toss an echo line in there above your if statement to see what's happening. Like `echo "Checking product ".$product_list." and it has count ".$data_exists;` Nothing about this problem makes sense. The ordering of the records in the database is meaningless from an RDBMS standpoint, which makes me agree with you that this is an issue in the While loop (or the loop is exiting for some other reason before it's allowed to carry out the delete). It's befuddling.

Comment: when I insert `row3(p_id=7)` first in cart, then `row4(p_id=3)` and `echo = 0 ?` but when I put `row3(p_id=3)`, then `row4(p_id=7)` and `echo = 2` (which is the result that I should get) `echo $data_exists; exit();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proble is the UPDATE query.

Table cart:

```
CREATE TABLE `cart` (
`cart_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ip_address` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If the user is not logged in, items are in the cart table with user_id = -1.
Otherwise, cart.user_id = true user id

The problem:

BEFORE

```
card_id product_id user_id
1       2000       10
2       2001       10
4       2001       -1
5       2002       -1
```

Run code...

AFTER

```
cart_id product_id user_id
1       2000       10
2       2001       10
5       2002       10
```

Next example:

BEFORE

```
cart_id product_id  user_id
1       2000        10
2       2001        10
5       2002        -1
6       2000        -1 <--- duplicate product, should be deleted
```

Run code...

AFTER

```
cart_id product_id user_id
1       2000        10
2       2001        10
5       2002        10
6       2000        10 <--- not deleted
```

The problem is this:

```
$update_cart = "UPDATE cart SET user_id='$userid' WHERE ip_address = '$ip_add' AND user_id = -1";
```

It is updating ALL the rows that match user_id and ip_addr, then on the next pass, the search fails so it does not delete the row that it should.

```
$sql = "SELECT product_id FROM cart WHERE user_id = -1 AND ip_address = '$ip_add' ";
$stmt = $heidisql->query($sql);

while ($test = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $product_list = $test['product_id'];

    $verify_cart_count = "SELECT COUNT(cart_id) FROM cart WHERE user_id= '$userid' AND product_id = $product_list";

    $verify_cart_row = $heidisql->query($verify_cart_count);
    $data_exists = $verify_cart_row->fetchColumn();
    echo "Looking for data user_id = {$userid}, product_id = {$product_list}\n";
    // echo $data_exists; exit();
    if ($data_exists < 1) {
        echo "Data exists\n";
        //if result = 0, userid will be updated
        // Bad
        // $update_cart = "UPDATE cart SET user_id='$userid' WHERE ip_address = '$ip_add' AND user_id = -1";
        // Fixed
        $update_cart = "UPDATE cart SET user_id='$userid' WHERE ip_address = '$ip_add' AND user_id = -1 AND product_id = $product_list";
        $update_cart_result = $heidisql->prepare($update_cart);
        $update_cart_result->execute();

    } else {
        echo "Data missing\n";
        //if result > 0, duplicate row need to be delete
        $remove_exist_product = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE user_id = -1 AND ip_address= '$ip_add' AND product_id = $product_list ";
        $remove_cart_result = $heidisql->prepare($remove_exist_product)->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: verifying the code, will mark you as correct answer if it work, wait a sec